# How to create a database later with a scala play-framework applicaton?

Tags: mysql, database, scala, playframework

I have an application written in scala play-framework. I have some credentials in the application config. When a user runs the application, the appliction will create a database for the user. The current configuration is given below.

```
db.rds.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.rds.host="localhost"
db.rds.port="3306"
db.rds.user = "root"
db.rds.password = "root"
```

As you can see that there is no **db.rds.url** or **db.rds.dbname**. That is because I haven't created a database yet. Later I will create a new database for the user with the users input.

Currently I am getting an error when I run the application. The error says **Missing configuration [db.rds.url]**

Is it possible? If so then how? I hope I have made myself clear. If you find anything confusing then please ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll probably have to control the life-cycle of the database plugin in some way, to have it disabled from the start, and then started later. I'm not sure how possible this is.

Comment: thanks, I couldn't find anything in the web either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Play Framework Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase#mysql-database-engine-connection-properties), when you are using the mysql engine, you should to provide the **url** configuration in contrast to **host** and **port** that you are informing.

If your intent is connect as **root** into mysql without accessing any specified database, try to supply the following:

```
db.rds.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.rds.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
db.rds.user = "root"
db.rds.password = "root"
```